# Ajax unobtrusive validation and MVC4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, validation, scripting

I'm trying to get my AJAX to work in a **PARTIAL VIEW**. I have included it at the top of my Layout page as:

```
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - COMIS</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

        <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")" rel="stylesheet" 
        type="text/css" />

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/DatePickerReady.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.1.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript">       
        </script>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") 
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css") 
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") /
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")


        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/buttons.js") 
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/navigation.js")
    </head>
```

However it's not working. It throws the error:"JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'unobtrusive' of undefined or null reference mvc 4".I think its because I'm referencing too many scripts. can someone please shoe me what I'm doing wrong?

**BUNDLE.config**

```
      public class BundleConfig
        {

            public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
            {
                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive-{version}.js"));

                bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")); 

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));


                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

                bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css", 
       "~/Content/PagedList.css"));

                bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css",
                            "~/Content/jquery-ui.css"));


                bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
   bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*.intellisense.js");
                bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*-vsdoc.js");
                bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*.debug.js", OptimizationMode.WhenEnabled);


            }
        }

**PARTIAL VIEW** - 

    @model COMIS.Models.X
    @using(Html.BeginForm("Create"))
         { @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        <fieldset class="innerform">
        <div>
            ....
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    } 


       <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: you have a lot of script references, check your BundleConfig.cs and see what you bundling. you might be referencing them more than once.

Comment: updated it to include my bundle.config @Burg

Comment: Remove all your `<script src="...` tags including for the partial views (your adding multiple copies of the scripts) and except for `modernizr`, move all the `@Scripts.Render(..` to immediately before the closing `</body>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Try referencing the scripts in order at the bottom of your Layout page.

Example:

```
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add all the other scripts to the BundleConfig.cs

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title - COMIS</title>
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css") 
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css") 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>

</body>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") /
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/buttons.js") 
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/navigation.js")



Edit

// BundleConfig.cs

// for js scripts
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/*Bundle Name*").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/file.js")); // location of your js file

// reference js bundle like this
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/*Bundle Name*")

// css
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/*Bundle Name*").Include(
                        "~/Content//css/file.css")); // location of css file

// reference css bundle like this
@Styles.Render("~/Content/*Bundle Name*")
```

Comment: the only thing i had to add was


            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/navigation").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/navigation-*"));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/knockout-*"));

 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/migrate").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/migrate-*"));

Comment: post some of your partial view. sometimes i have found that you have to add the <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> add the bottom of the partial view and then have your ajax script underneath that within script tags :)